# Multiple OR operators with elem.value.match

Tags: javascript

I've been writing a javascript function which returns true if the value matches one of about 4 values (just 3 in the example below). The problem is, when I have just two values the function works correctly, but adding a third breaks the code.

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm guessing there's a much better way of doing this? I've tried searching but found nothing as of yet.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
function isValid(elem, helperMsg){

                var sn6 = /[sS][nN]6/;
                var sn5 = /[sS][nN]5/;
                var sn38 = /[sS][nN]38/;

                if(elem.value.match(sn6 || sn5 || sn38)){
                        //do stuff
                        return true;
                }else{

                        return false;
                }
            }
```

Edit:

Here's my second attempt with an array:

```
    function isLocal(elem, helperMsg){
        var validPostcodes=new Array();
            validPostcodes[0]= /[wW][rR]12/;       
            validPostcodes[1]= /[cC][vV]35/;
            validPostcodes[2]= /[sS][nN]99/;
            validPostcodes[3]= /[sS][nN]6/;
            validPostcodes[4]= /[sS][nN]5/;
            validPostcodes[5]= /[sS][nN]38/;
            validPostcodes[6]= /[oO][xX]29/;
            validPostcodes[7]= /[oO][xX]28/;

        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < validPostcodes.length; ++i) {
            if(elem.value.match(validPostcodes[i])){
                    // do stuff
                    return true;
            }else{
                    alert(helperMsg);
                    elem.focus();
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a || b || c
```

is an expression that evaluates to a boolean.  That means that you're running either `match(true)` or `match(false)`.  You must write it as:

```
match(a) || match(b) || match(c)
```

Another option would be to store them in an array and loop over it.  That would mean if the number of patterns grew you wouldn't have to change code other than the list of patterns.  Another approach, though limited to this situation, might be to change the pattern to one that  is equivalent to or-ing the three options together (untested, and I'm a bit rusty on regex):

```
elem.value.match(/[sSnN][6|5|38]/)
```

Array based example:

```
var patterns = [/../, /.../];
for (var i = 0; i < patterns.length; ++i) {
    if (elem.value.match(patterns[i])) { return true; }
}
```

In real code, I would probably format it like this:

```
function isValid(elem, helperMsg){
    var patterns = [/../, /.../],
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < patterns.length; ++i) {
        if (elem.value.match(patterns[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

That's just a habit though since JavaScript hoists variables to the top of their scope.  It's by no means required to declare the variables like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will have a few more read throughs and try to dissect it. Unfortunately, the regex answer won't work as there will be other postcodes that don't start with sn.

Comment: Ah.  In that case, I'd probably go with the array approach.  If there's anything in particular you need help understanding, let me know and I'll gladly edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to be trying this over the next hour so I will be sure to let you know/accept your answer.

Comment: I've just tried it and added my code to my initial post - with the array it works ok for the first item in the array, but the rest are returning false.

Comment: You're code is not functionally equivalent.  In the for loop, you're checking each pattern against the element.  Therefore, if a failed pattern is reached before a matching pattern, the else is executed, the alert is done, and the function returns false.  What you'll need to do is set a flag that default to false.  Then loop over the possible patterns.  If any pattern matches, set the flag to true.  Then, outside of the loop, check if the flag is true or not.

Comment: Great, thanks for the example - I'll get back to you shortly :).

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly - thanks so much for your help! Definitely a good few lessons to remember in here.